# Is it possible to create a generic @helper method with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to write a helper in Razor that looks like the following:

```
@helper DoSomething<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expr) where T : class
```

Unfortunately, the parser thinks that `<T` is the beginning of an HTML element and I end up with a syntax error.  Is it possible to create a helper with Razor that is a generic method?  If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Still not fixed in the current MVC 4 release. :(

Comment: How is this still not fixed in VS2012?

Comment: Goodness, I can't wait for this to be added; I hope this is somewhere around "*implement it yesterday*" on the priority list. Partially off-topic, but alongside this, I'd like to see that the generated classes are `static`, unless implementation details prohibit it; reason being, is one could use *generic extension helpers*: `@helper Foo<T>(this T o) where T : IBar { }`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. You could write a normal HTML helper instead.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DoSomething<T, U>(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<T, U>> expr
) where T : class
{
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
@(Html.DoSomething<SomeModel, string>(x => x.SomeProperty))
```

or if you are targeting the model as first generic argument:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DoSomething<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expr
) where TModel : class
{
    ...
}
```

which will allow you to invoke it like this (assuming of course that your view is strongly typed, but that's a safe assumption because all views should be strongly typed anyways :-)):

```
@Html.DoSomething(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Comment: Hopefully this is something they add to a future version of Razor helpers.  The readability of a traditional helper is much lower than the @helper syntax.

Comment: Yeah agreed. Reverting to the older method not only sucks, but splits your helpers up arbitrarily!

Answer (score 130):

This **is** possible to achieve inside a helper file with the `@functions` syntax but if you want the razor-style readability you are referring to you will also need to call a regular helper to do the HTML fit and finish.

Note that functions in a Helper file are static so you would still need to pass in the HtmlHelper instance from the page if you were intending to use its methods.

e.g.
Views\MyView.cshtml:

```
@MyHelper.DoSomething(Html, m=>m.Property1)
@MyHelper.DoSomething(Html, m=>m.Property2)
@MyHelper.DoSomething(Html, m=>m.Property3)
```

App_Code\MyHelper.cshtml:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@functions
{
    public static HelperResult DoSomething<TModel, TItem>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> expr)
    {
        return TheThingToDo(html.LabelFor(expr), html.EditorFor(expr), html.ValidationMessageFor(expr));
    }
}
@helper TheThingToDo(MvcHtmlString label, MvcHtmlString textbox, MvcHtmlString validationMessage)
{
    <p>
        @label
        <br />
        @textbox
        @validationMessage
    </p>
}
...
```

Comment: You do NOT have to make the method static, and thus you also do NOT need to pass your Html/Url/Model etc

Comment: Hmmm why doesn't this work for me? I get a "Cannot access non-static method 'TheThingToDo' in static context"..

Comment: This worked for me once I removed the static keyword from the "DoSomething" method signature.

Comment: @Sheepy, that's only half true.  You are correct you can make them non-static, but you only get `System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper` rather than `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`.  There's an excellent chance that the `WebPages` version will not be suitable for you, since most extension methods are written against `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`.  Furthermore, there is no `Url` property, and `UrlHelper` requires a `RequestContext` which is unavailable in the `WebPages` version.  All in all you're probably going to have to pass in the `Mvc` `HtmlHelper`.

Comment: the helper must be part of App_Code Folder ??

Comment: Yes, this file must be placed in `{MyMvcProject}\App_Code\`. It doesn't work as advertised when you place it elsewhere. The error *Cannot access non-static method 'TheThingToDo' in static context* disappears when you move `MyHelper.cshtml` into `App_Code`.
`DoSomething` should be static, so that you can call `@MyHelper.DoSomething(..)` in your view. If you make it non-static, you'd need to create an instance of `MyHelper` first.

Comment: When used together with RazorGenerator you'll need to specify the "Generator: MvcHelper" option else you'll get the same static method not found error. That solution is documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378829/is-there-an-example-on-using-razor-to-generate-a-static-html-page/31609879#31609879

Comment: Extremely underrated answer.  This should be marked as the correct answer.  Not only that, this technique allows you to write much more elegant HTML helper methods by using the Razor markup.

Answer (score 3):

In all cases the `TModel` will be the same (the model declared for the view), and in my case, the `TValue` was going to be the same, so I was able to declare the Expression argument type:

```
@helper FormRow(Expression<Func<MyViewModel, MyClass>> expression) {
  <div class="form-group">
    @(Html.LabelFor(expression, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-6 text-right" }))
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)
  </div>
}
```

If your model fields are all `string`, then you can replace `MyClass` with `string`.

It might not be bad to define two or three helpers with the `TValue` defined, but if you have any more that would generate some ugly code, I didn't really find a good solution. I tried wrapping the `@helper` from a function I put inside the `@functions {}` block, but I never got it to work down that path.

Comment: Kind of obvious when you think about it - if it's `TModel` you probably know it in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if your main problem is to get **name** attribute value for binding using lambda expression seems like the `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyPoperty)`, and if your component having very complex html tags and should be implemented on razor helper, then why don't just create an extension method of `HtmlHelper<TModel>` to resolve the binding name:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class MyHelpers
    {
        public static string GetNameForBinding<TModel, TProperty>
           (this HtmlHelper<TModel> model, 
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
        {
            return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(property);
        }
    }
}
```

your razor helper should be like usual:

```
@helper MyComponent(string name)
{
    <input name="@name" type="text"/>
}
```

then here you can use it

```
@TheHelper.MyComponent(Html.GetNameForBinding(x => x.MyProperty))
```

Comment: Isn't this what @Html.IdFor(...) is for?

Comment: Yes, you can do with `@Htm.IdFor` but need extra process to convert it to string (`.ToHtmlString()`) where the helper require string