# Global functions in razor view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to have a global method like `w` in my razor view engine for localization my MVC application. I tried

```
@functions{
    public string w(string message)
    {
        return VCBox.Helpers.Localization.w(message);
    }
}
```

but I should have this in my every razor pages and I don't want that. **I want to know how can I have a global function that can be used in every pages of my project?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an extension method:

```
namespace System
{    
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string w(this string message)
        {
            return VCBox.Helpers.Localization.w(message);  
        }
    }
}
```

Called like so:

```
"mymessage".w();
```

Or:

```
string mymessage = "mymessage";
mymessage.w();
```

Or:

```
Extensions.w("mymessage");
```

Comment: as you see I can use `VCBox.Helpers.Localization.w(message);` but I need a better way!

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee. The shortest you're going to get will have a "." in it. How do you define "better way"?

Comment: I want something like `w` as Wordpress and other apps have. there is a `write` method to write something and now I want to have `w` to write but localized write.

Comment: Write the extension method against the ViewPage instead. `public static string w(this ViewPage view, string message){/* do stuff */}`. Then you should be able to do a straight `w("mymessage")`.

Comment: I tried it but compiler didn't find `w`. I also added `<add namespace="VCBox.Helpers"/>` into the `<namespace>` section in `web.config`

Comment: Try removing the namespace completely from the extension class.

Comment: If you add an extension method to the viewpage you would still need to do `this.w("message")`. You are always going to need the `something.w("message")`. If you wan't short, best bet is string extension method and calling it as `"message".w()`

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the HtmlHelper:

Extensions:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString W(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string message)
    {
        return VCBox.Helpers.Localization.w(message);
    }
}
```

Cshtml:

```
@Html.W("message")
```

Comment: isn't there any way to have just `w` method?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Not without declaring it in the current scope (like you did in the example in you question).

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760783/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-helper-method-with-razor