# Why `w("hi")` doesn't work but `this.w("hi")` work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the 'this' keyword required to call an extension method from within the extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510964/why-is-the-this-keyword-required-to-call-an-extension-method-from-within-the-e)

I want to localization my MVC application then I want to use `w(message)` method and as 
"flem" answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204410/global-functions-in-razor-view-engine) I have this code:

```
namespace System.Web.WebPages
{
    public static class Localization
    {
        public static string w(this WebPageBase page, string message)
        {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

but in razor page(`page.cshtml`) I can't use `@w("hi")` but `@this.w("hi")` works. **I want to know how it is possible to `this.method()` works but `method()` doesn't work?**

Comment: I assume because w is an extension method and it has to have an object to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a static method you have to specify which class the method belongs to.

In your case, because this is an extension method `this` is referring to the current page which is of type `WebPageBase`. So `this.w("hi")` is effectively the same as you are writing:

```
@WebPageBase.w("hi")
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
@Localization.w(this, "hi")
```

Comment: The method belongs to `Localization` and is an extension method.  An object of type `WebPageBase` is required to call the method, which is why `this` is required.

Answer (score 2):

`w` is an extension method and the way they work is that the object you call it on is put in place of the parameter specified by `this` in the method signature.

In the case of `this.w` you are specifying the object it shoudl work on.

if you jsut call `w("")` then you are not specifying that first parameter.

I assume you are thinking that if it was a method of that object then the two calls would be the same and this is true. However, the difference is that there is no method in scope which is just `w`. That method is in another class and its only the magic of extension methods that allows it to work in the correct circumstances.

Comment: Remember that extension methods are just syntax sugar.  It is the same as `Localization.w(this, "")`.  Not specifying `this` would be the same as Localization.w("")`.  This overload does not exist.

Comment: @cadrell0: Yeah, maybe should have been more explicit but the linked duplicate just says everything that needs to be said now so I wouldn't bother editing my answer any more. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have created an extension method for WebPageBase.
It should be called using an object WebPageBase or a derived object.
In your case `this` is the correct object to use (Probably a Page object)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx