# How to Accept Generics Argument of Any Type?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have a generic class.

```
public class PagerInfo<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

And I want to pass an instance of this class to a method in another class.

```
public void Pagination(PagerInfo pagerInfo)
{
    // ...
}
```

The method above won't compile because I didn't provide a type argument. But what if I want this method to work regardless of the type. That is, I want this method to operate on a `PagerInfo` instances regardless of the type. And my method will not access any type-specific methods or properties.

*Also, note that my actual method is in an ASP.NET MVC cshtml helper method and not a regular cs file.*

Comment: `public void Pagination<T>(PagerInfo<T> pagerInfo)`?

Comment: You know, I think you are right. I guess it doesn't work because it's in a cshtml file, and `@helper Pagination<T>(string url, PagerInfo<T> pagerInfo)` fails with the error *Expected a "(" after the helper name.*

Comment: IC - not sure what to do about that. Issue with razor then. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760783/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-helper-method-with-razor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the method does not access the members of the type that use the generic type parameter, then it's common to define a non-generic base type from which the generic type derives:

```
public abstract class PagerInfo
{
    // Non-generic members
}

public class PagerInfo<T> : PagerInfo
{
    // Generic members
}
```

```csharp
public void Pagination(PagerInfo pagerInfo)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: An interface may be better as it would still allow the class `PagerInfo<T>` to inherit from another class if need be.