# How to generate menu item in razor view from entity type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper, razor-2

How to generate menu item html in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor view from entity type like

```
@(Html.LiEntity<Customer>())
```

I tried code below based on answer in             [Is it possible to create a generic @helper method with Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760783/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-helper-method-with-razor)

and in comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011675/how-to-get-type-attribute-in-razor

but got compile error about Url is not defined.

```
public static class LiEntityHelper
{
    public static string LiEntity<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : EntityBase
    {
        return @"<li><a href='" + Url.Action("Index", "Home", new
                {
           _user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
              }) +
            @"'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bar-chart></i>
     <span>" + LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI.Get<TEntity>() + @"</span></a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting..?

Comment: you are using Context specific method like Url.Action inside static method, which is not right.